# What is the average value for the top quarter of a sine wave?

Tags: calculus, average

Say we have a sine wave with the peak value of 1. What is the average value of the top quarter of this sine wave? If you want some context it is for a diode question where the top quarter of a voltage is positive so im looking for the average voltage value of this part of the sine wave.

Comment: the average value $=\frac {\int_a^b f(x) dx}{b-a}$

Comment: So that would be int from pi/4 to 3pi/4 of sinx all over pi/2 ? Coming to an answer of 0.90031?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean 
$$I=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$ 
where $a$ is the value $x_1$ that results in $\sin(x_1)=\frac{3}{4}$ and $b$ is similarly $x_2$ such that $\sin(x_2)=1$?

Can you calculate the rest? If not, let me know.

I get

> $I\approx 0.9152\dots$